# How to access and return specific value of a foreach in PHP

Tags: php

So I have a request-response that looks like this

```
$json='[ {"item_cat":"Stationary","items":[{"item_name":"A4 Paper","qty":"2"},{"item_name":"Test Paper","qty":"6"}],"total":"2"},
{"item_cat":"Computer Accessory ","items":[{"item_name":"Power pack","qty":"2"}],"total":"1"},
{"item_cat":"Material","items":[{"item_name":"T-Shirt","qty":"3"},
{"item_name":"Cap","qty":"5"}],"total":"2"}]';
```

I'm trying to get each item_name and qty so I can use them to manipulate my db. Here is what I've done

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);
$len = count($data);

    for($i =0; $i< $len; $i++){
            $item_length = count($data[$i]['items']);

        for($c=0; $c < $item_length; $c++){
            foreach ($data[$i]['items'][$c] as $key => $value ) {

                $qty = '';
                if($key == "qty"){
                    $qty = $data[$i]['items'][$c];
                    }

                if($key == 'item_name'){
                    $item_name = "$value";
                    }

                    $sql= $db->query("SELECT `stock` from `inventory` WHERE `item_name` = '$item_name'");
                    while ($sql1 = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
                            $stock = $sql1['stock'];
                  }

                    if($stock > $qty ){

                        $stock_balance = $stock - $qty;

                    $quantity = (int)$qty;

                         $db->query("UPDATE `inventory` SET `stock` =  (`stock` - '$quantity')   WHERE `item_name` = '$item_name'");
                    }else{
                        echo "<h3> This Operation Not Allowed: Stock Balance Is Less Than The Request <h3>";
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

A non-numeric value encountered, which is as a result of $qty because I'm not able to return just qty value. I've tried several other means. I'm really exhausted. Would appreciate any help please. Cheers!

Comment: `$item_name = "$value";` what does this code do?

Comment: Returns the values for item_name(s) in the surface but it actually returns for all other keys. I got to know when trying to work with the results it returns from the qty key. I cast it into integer then the others that are not showing results in 0s. So there is an inner workings of that function(foreach) that I don't get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's decompose your code.

This is json:

```json
[
   {
      "item_cat":"Stationary",
      "items":[
         {
            "item_name":"A4 Paper",
            "qty":"2"
         },
         {
            "item_name":"Test Paper",
            "qty":"6"
         }
      ],
      "total":"2"
   },
   {
      "item_cat":"Computer Accessory ",
      "items":[
         {
            "item_name":"Power pack",
            "qty":"2"
         }
      ],
      "total":"1"
   },
   {
      "item_cat":"Material",
      "items":[
         {
            "item_name":"T-Shirt",
            "qty":"3"
         },
         {
            "item_name":"Cap",
            "qty":"5"
         }
      ],
      "total":"2"
   }
]
```

Now the array loop without the SQL (to ensure that it works as expected):

```php
$data = json_decode($json, true);
$len = count($data);

    for($i =0; $i< $len; $i++){
            $item_length = count($data[$i]['items']);

        for($c=0; $c < $item_length; $c++){
            foreach ($data[$i]['items'][$c] as $key => $value ) {

                $qty = '';
                if($key == "qty"){
                    $qty = $data[$i]['items'][$c];
                    }

                if($key == 'item_name'){
                    $item_name = "$value";
                    }
```

The problems here are: un-human variable names and not correct working with JSON object.

First of all, let us rename variables to something readable.

Example:

- `$data[$i]` will be `$catalog_entry` (object)
- `$data[$i]['items']` will be `$catalog_entry_items` (array)
- `$data[$i]['items'][$c]` will be `$catalog_entry_item` (one item, object)

Let's change the code with new variables:

```php
$data = json_decode($json, true);
$len = count($data);

for($i =0; $i< $len; $i++) {
    $catalog_entry = $data[$i];
    $catalog_entry_items = $data[$i]['items'];
    
    for($c=0; $c < sizeof($catalog_entry_items); $c++) {
        $catalog_entry_item = $data[$i]['items'][$c];
        $qty = $catalog_entry_item['qty'];
        $item_name = $catalog_entry_item['item_name'];
        echo $item_name . ' : ' . $qty . "\n"; // <-- this is for testing
    }
}
```

[Run this code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a79b8a107010af63f95e212d5a1c48678bc636e3) and see the expected result:

```
A4 Paper : 2
Test Paper : 6
Power pack : 2
T-Shirt : 3
Cap : 5
```

Good, now we have `qty` and `item_name`.

Let's make queries. First look at your code:

```php
$sql= $db->query("SELECT `stock` from `inventory` WHERE `item_name` = '$item_name'");
                    while ($sql1 = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
                            $stock = $sql1['stock'];
                  }
```

Two strange things: 1) possible SQL injection, 2) replace `$stock` variable many times with new value (if we have more than 1 row for item in `inventory`).

Anyway, if this code is working (I can't check), then we come to next part:

```php
if ($stock > $qty ) {
    $stock_balance = $stock - $qty;
    $quantity = (int)$qty;
    $db->query("UPDATE `inventory` SET `stock` =  (`stock` - '$quantity')   WHERE `item_name` = '$item_name'");
} else {
    echo "<h3> This Operation Not Allowed: Stock Balance Is Less Than The Request <h3>";
}
```

First, unnecessary cast to integer, so remove line `$quantity = (int)$qty;` and put `$stock_balance` into query. We will have:

```php
if ($stock >= $qty ) {
    $stock_balance = $stock - $qty;
    $db->query("UPDATE `inventory` SET `stock` =  $stock_balance WHERE `item_name` = '$item_name'");
} else {
    echo "<h3> This Operation Not Allowed: Stock Balance Is Less Than The Request <h3>";
}
```

...well... not only you are exhausted, so I will end now. Ask if something is not correct or not understandable.

Comment: what if `$stock == $qty`... conditional `if ($stock > $qty ) { ...} else {...}` should be `if ($stock >= $qty ) { ...} else {...}`

Comment: @jibsteroos thanks for pointing me. I was excited writing so much text... =)

Comment: No worries Anton ;-)

Comment: @Anton I appreciate a lot. I've read through your codes and believe, when I run them, it should work as expected as I can't at the moment but once I do and it works I would let you know. I'm so grateful.

Comment: @Anton thanks once again. It worked just fine, and as touching the two fears you raised as touching SQL injection and multiple rows entries. The data was escaped when receiving and there are no two rows with the same item name. Cheers!